# Data is sorting based on the order it is added instead of the position it is added

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to add a data in the middle and save. The data is getting saved at the end but I want it to save in the position I have added it.
Say suppose I want to add Boolean_1 in the middle of Boolean_2 and Boolean_3 and save, it gets saved at the bottom instead of getting saved at the middle. After Save it fetches the record from DB and displays and in DB it is getting sorted based on the order it is added.

[image]

I have added the stored procedure I am using for it.

`ALTER Procedure [dbo].[ACTION_ATTRIBUTE_List_Get_sp] (`
`@ruleIdParam uniqueidentifier)`
`AS`

`SELECT aa.CFG_ACTION_ATTRIBUTE_ID,`
`aa.NAME AS NAME,`
`aa.INSTANCE_ID,`
`ISNULL(CAST(aa.VALUE as nvarchar(max)), aa.VALUE_EX) VALUE,`
`aa.DESCRIPTION,`
`v.NAME AS VARIABLE_NAME,`
`v.IMAGE_LOCATION,`
`aa.INTERNAL_SEQUENCE`
`FROM CFG_ACTION_ATTRIBUTE aa,`
`CFG_VARIABLE v`
`WHERE  aa.CFG_VARIABLE_ID = v.CFG_VARIABLE_ID`
`AND    aa.CFG_RULE_ID = @ruleIdParam`
`order by aa.INTERNAL_SEQUENCE;`
`GO`

I tried ordering it by the Internal Sequence but didnt work. Can it be done programmatically using C#? Any suggestions please?

Comment: All I see is a `SELECT` statement. Your question is about storing the data. What exactly do want to achieve?

Comment: @PaulSinnema have edited my question. Please check now.

Comment: With 'store' you mean on your page? Show the code you use to attempt that please.